# Can't call arrow function from another arrow function in Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrow-functions

Consider the code :

```
module.exports = class SuperGenerator {
    Generate = packageId => {

        // ... 
        TestMe();

    }


    TestMe = () => {
        console.log("Test Me...");
    };  

}
```

When I run the code `TestMe` is not invoked.

Why ?

Comment: How are you invoking?

Comment: Try defining TestMe before you call it. And someone should make an instance of your class then call the generate method.

Comment: @Eldar: Of course I make an instance ... but nothing happens regarding `TestMe`

Comment: Sorry couldn't read the code clearly. It's not a local function to Generate it's an instance member of SuperGenerator so you should call it by this.TestMe()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there are a couple things. If you are talking about class functions then you'll need to call them with `this` (e.g. `this.TestMe()`) but if you are talking about two functional expressions they aren't hoisted so you'll have to define them before you want to use them.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `this.TestMe()` instead if simple `TestMe()`